# Microsoft.Unity inside MVC async support

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, unity-container

We are using Microsoft Unity for Dependency Injection. During ResolveAll objects are  created, and some of them need to call to async methods for initialization.
I know that MVC app uses a special ThreadContext, but couldn't figure out which context (and how) to use during the object construction by unity.

This the bootstrap logic:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
// register dependency resolver for WebAPI 
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

Looks like resolve all is being called in the context:

```
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Type controllerType, out System.Func<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController> activator)    Unknown
```

If I try just to call `GetMethodAsync().Result` during unity's resolveall the call gets hanged indefinitely.

How should the async method be called to be executed in a synchronous way?

Comment: You are using correct way of calling async method synchronously and it expected to deadlock in ASP.Net app exactly as you observe (search should give you related answers and hacks trying to work around it). You probably should rethink your approach to avoid async calls during DI resolution....

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov. DI resolution should be completely synchronous, since [constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). All other initialization should be moved to a later point in time.

Comment: Agree on constructor timings. What is the correct time to do the async initialization? Doing it at page request is too late.

Comment: I don't know much about asp.net-mvc, is there some bootstrapping logic? Like the `Main` method of an exe? It's probably where you instanciate the `IUnityContainer` and do all your `Register`'s. I guess it would be beneficial if you would "cache" (singleton - `ContainerControllerLifetimeManager`?!) this instance which requires expensive initialization. If you do so, you can just do `container.resolve<ExpensiveType>().InitializeSync()` after the last `Register`.

Comment: There is `void Application_Start()` - the place where the unity container get's configured, however the actual `ResolveAll()` happens in mvc's context (see `DependencyResolver` assignment). Also sync - is something I'm trying to avoid - I need an async, so that several independent pieces can be initialized in parallel using tasks and that controllers could wait asynchronously as well, in case if expensive initialization is still not completed.